# tinyMCE error while form submission

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3, tinymce-4

I am using tinyMCE-4.0.16 in a form in cakePHP2.4. When i click on submit, form does not submit and gives following error in console

An invalid form control with name='data[Research][description]' is not focusable.

I am using HTML5 validation "required" in textarea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148080/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable)

Comment: is that the name of the array, and array field?

Comment: Have you tried using different browsers?

Comment: it's not tiny MCE, it's a PHP error.

Answer (score 2):

If the textarea is hidden, but it is set to "required" via HTML, it will throw that error... You're going to have to either remove "required," or have the element displayed when the form submits...