# Why is my form not submitting?

Tags: php, forms, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I am using zurb's foundation as my css framework and unfortunately it won't let me submit the form. Even if I fill out everything and click the submit button nothing happens. Here is my current code.

```
  <div class="row panel clearfix">
     <div class="small-9 large-centered columns">
        <form action="record-time-out.php" method="POST" data-abide>
           <div class="small-8" >
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="small-3 columns">
                    <label class="right">PURPOSE</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="small-9 columns">
                    <input type="text" name="txt_purpose" required>
                    <small class="error">Input your purpose.</small>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="small-8">
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="small-3 columns">
                    <label class="right">DESTINATION</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="small-9 columns">
                    <input type="text" name="txt_destination" required>
                    <small class="error">Input your destination.</small>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="small-8">
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="small-3 columns">
                    <label class="right">Expected TIME-IN</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="small-9 columns">
                    <input type="text" name="txt_time" required>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
              <div class="small-3 columns">
              </div>
              <div class="small-9 columns">
                 <input type="submit" class="button" value="OUT"/> 
              </div>
           </div>
        </form>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Where is your PHP code? Any errors showing? Add an attribute `name` for your submit button too...

Comment: I think it is, but i suspect you are not collecting properly.

I would need to see the php code but to check its actually submitting

Add **<?php print_r($_POST); ?>** to the top of record-time-out.php

Comment: Same, I just confirmed that the form can submit. I think your problem lies else where.

Comment: @bcesars It is working already, weird

Comment: @Chris working already, weird

Comment: @Chris I tried and it didn't work, not even loading or what

Comment: if you have your php file already setup omit the php open and close tags you dont need them twice just use the print_r($_POST);

It should just throw out an array it wont look pretty but its not meant to, if you want something more legible add echo '<pre>'; and echo '</pre>'; on the lines before and after respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the form code is always executed by the browser, so it won't know where is the "record-time-out.php"
My suggestion is just add the url of your site and it will work, test it, would be something like this:

```
<div class="row panel clearfix">
 <div class="small-9 large-centered columns">
    <form action="http://example.com/record/record-time-out.php" method="POST" data-abide>
       <div class="small-8" >
          <div class="row">
             <div class="small-3 columns">
                <label class="right">PURPOSE</label>
             </div>
             <div class="small-9 columns">
                <input type="text" name="txt_purpose" required>
                <small class="error">Input your purpose.</small>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="small-8">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="small-3 columns">
                <label class="right">DESTINATION</label>
             </div>
             <div class="small-9 columns">
                <input type="text" name="txt_destination" required>
                <small class="error">Input your destination.</small>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="small-8">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="small-3 columns">
                <label class="right">Expected TIME-IN</label>
             </div>
             <div class="small-9 columns">
                <input type="text" name="txt_time" required>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="small-3 columns">
          </div>
          <div class="small-9 columns">
             <input type="submit" class="button" value="OUT"/> 
          </div>
       </div>
    </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: As long as the html file and php file are in the same directory then relative links are perfectly acceptable and can aid in portability if you happen to develop in one directory and then copy and paste into another final directory.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you.

Add

```
<small class="error">Input Expected TIME-IN.</small>
```

after Expected TIME-IN text box.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `novalidate` might help.

```
<form action="record-time-out.php" method="POST" data-abide novalidate>
```

In your form, You might have hidden input having required attribute.

Comment: What exactly does novalidate do?

Comment: @FewFlyBy It ignores `required`. You have to validate inputs using JavaScript or you have to fix 'required's. In your form, You might have hidden input having required attribute.

Comment: It already worked without the novalidate. So can I just remove novalidate already?

Comment: @FewFlyBy You added, it worked. Now you removed, it's still working? It's because of cache. Press `ctrl + F5` and check again.

Comment: @FewFlyBy also take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148080/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable

Comment: @FewFlyBy So unfortunately you need to add `novalidate`

Comment: @FewFlyBy Go to developer mode (press `ctrl + shift + c`) then go to console tab and see what error occurs when you click on submit button.