# No longer able to create Wordpress pages

Tags: javascript, wordpress, blogs

I'm using Wordpress for my blog and from some weeks I'm no longer able to create pages !!

I try to create a new page and when I clic on **Publish**, nothing happens. I also tried to use Google Chrome to inspect the **Publish button** I get this error :

```
An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable.
```

I use Wordpress 4.1.1

Comment: disable plugins until you find a culprit

Comment: Maybe you can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148080/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable

Comment: @Solutions Thank you so much, but it's not the same case, it happens for me when I want to create a new page.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from Twitter official wordpress plugin.Then, You just need to disable the plugin and everything is OK.