# Before Html 5 validation trigger event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an Html 5 form with input elements contains required constraint. A user can view this form in edit or view mode. Means, I am hiding the input controls if form is in view mode and showing span instead. There is a submit button. Whenever user click the submit button and form is in view mode then I will get,

```
An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable.
```

I tried to show the form in edit mode during form submit event but I am getting this error prior to submit event invocation. How to fix this error? Is there any event just before validation happens?

Answer (score 2):

Per [user2909164](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2909164/user2909164)'s answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148080/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable), adding a **novalidate** attribute to the form should fix the issue:

```
<form name="myform" novalidate>
```