# An invalid form control with name='article[content]' is not focusable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-modal

```
<%= f.text_area :content, :class => "form-control", :id => "summer-body", :required => true %>
```

is not working when i used the

```
:required => true
```

This is the error:

> An invalid form control with `name='article[content]'` is not focusable

But when I try to remove the class and id, it works.

Comment: Yes.  That means some css which is targeted at the id or class is the problem.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148080/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable

Comment: Try changes sequence of attribute will also help or try follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148080/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable