# POST Error on HTML Side

Tags: javascript, html, forms

When I try to POST a form on HTML, an error returns(I can see it on console) and form not posting.

Error(on Console):

```
An invalid form control with name='shortText' is not focusable
```

You can find my HTML below:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="http://sava.com.tr/web/tr/yonetim/hizmet-ekle" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <fieldset class="content-group">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">İçerik Dili</label>
         <div class="col-lg-10">
            <select class="bootstrap-select" data-width="100%" name="langCode">
               <option value="1" >Türkçe</option>
               <option value="2" >English</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Ana Hizmet</label>
         <div class="col-lg-10">
            <select class="bootstrap-select" data-width="100%" name="main">
               <option value="0" >Hayır</option>
               <option value="1" >Evet</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">İçerik Görseli</label>
         <div class="col-lg-10">
            <div class="media no-margin-top">
               <div class="media-body">
                  <input type="file" class="file-styled" name="userfile">
                  <span class="help-block">Dosya boyutu en fazla 5 MB olabilir. Desteklenen formatlar: PNG/JPG/JPEG</span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-lg-2">İsim</label>
         <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" name="title" value="" placeholder="İsim" class="form-control" required="required"  />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-lg-2">Kısa Açıklama</label>
         <div class="col-lg-10">
            <textarea name="shortText" cols="40" rows="4" placeholder="Kısa Açıklama" class="summernote"></textarea>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-lg-2">İçerik</label>
         <div class="col-lg-10">
            <textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="4" placeholder="İçerik" class="summernote" ></textarea>
         </div>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <div class="text-right">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" >Ekle <i class="icon-circle-right2 position-right"></i></button>
   </div>
</form>
```

By the way, it only happens on Chrome and Firefox Windows version. In Mac OS, it's working perfect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148080/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable

Comment: I checked it but novalidate thing is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because a required field is not filled.
In your case the field

```
<textarea name="shortText" cols="40" rows="4" placeholder="Kısa Açıklama" class="summernote" required="required" ></textarea>
```

might not have been filled

Comment: Sorry, I added old codes. Now I changed it, please check. At this time there is no required on shortText textarea.

Comment: can you add a sample POST request body to your question @DenizB.

Comment: No its not related to that because he have two textarea. And input text field is also empty

Answer (score 0):

Add `novalidate` in your form tag

```
<form name="yourformname" novalidate>
```