# An invalid form control with name...is not focusable

Tags: javascript, jquery

**An invalid form control with name='additional_here_about_other_field' is not focusable.**
This code is for a select field with four dropdowns. A couple of the options are to be required: `#additional_here_about_other_field` and the `#additional_who_is_your_orthodontist_field`. When a required field is selected, you have to enter additional data in another text field that will show/unhide. When you select a required option and then switch to an option which is required or not and try to submit the form, you get the is not focusable error. It seems when you select a required field and then switch to another field, the previous required field although now hidden is still waiting to be validated?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 
 if(jQuery("#additional_here_about_other_field").length > 0){
  jQuery("#additional_here_about_other_field").hide();
  jQuery("#additional_how_did_u_hear_about_harp").change(function(){
   if(jQuery(this).val() == 'Other (please specify)'){ jQuery("#additional_here_about_other_field").show().prop('required',true); }
   else { jQuery("#additional_here_about_other_field").hide(); }
  });
 }
 if(jQuery("#additional_who_is_your_orthodontist").length > 0){
  jQuery("#additional_who_is_your_orthodontist").hide();
  jQuery("#additional_how_did_u_hear_about_harp").change(function(){
   if(jQuery(this).val() == 'Orthodontist Referral'){ jQuery("#additional_who_is_your_orthodontist").show().prop('required',true); }
   else { jQuery("#additional_who_is_your_orthodontist").hide(); }
  });
 }
});
```

```
HTML snippet
```

```html
<select name="additional_how_did_u_hear_about_harp" id="additional_how_did_u_hear_about_harp" class="select " data-allow_clear="true" data-placeholder="How Did You Hear About The Harp?" >
 <option value=""  selected='selected'></option>
 <option value="Patient" >Patient</option>
 <option value="Orthodontist Referral" >Orthodontist Referral</option>
 <option value="Trade Show" >Trade Show</option>
 <option value="Mailer" >Mailer</option>
 <option value="Other (please specify)" >Other (please specify)</option>
</select>

<div class="clear"></div>
<p>  
 <input type="text" class="input-text " name="additional_here_about_other_field" id="additional_here_about_other_field" placeholder="Other (please specify)"   value=""  />
</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<p>  
 <input type="text" class="input-text " name="additional_who_is_your_orthodontist" id="additional_who_is_your_orthodontist" placeholder="Who is your orthodontist?"   value=""  />
</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: for those finding this error message search result with custom elements and form participation there may be a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69684377

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just because a form control is hidden doesn't mean it isn't required. And since it is required, but hidden the browser can't focus the form control.

Every place you have `.hide()` change it to `.hide().prop('required',false)` to fix your problem.

Comment: What if you have multiple tabs in a form (for multiple languages). How can you fix this? There are 6 inputs per language, so simply displaying them in 1 form would make it very long.

Comment: @nclsvh you would have to implement the form validation yourself instead of relying on the browser for validation. I prefer this method because it standardizes the user experience across all browsers.

Comment: True, and having `<input type="hidden">` wil only hide the input, not the label and related stuff around. This sucks!

Comment: Make sense! It should remove the required attribute right away if you are hiding the controls and mark it as required.

Answer (score 4):

Remove "required" from the  field, and use a javascript logic to see if it has been required or not.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove "required" from the field. Then use this jQuery code:

```
$('#your_input_or_select_id').prop('required',true);   //use this to add required while document ready
$('#your_input_or_select_id').removeAttr('required'); //use this to remove required whenever you want
```