# Required for html input with label

Tags: html, css, forms, css-selectors

i use `label` + hidden `input`.file for customize CSS style.

But when i add a `required` attribute , it does not work.

In console log: An invalid form control with `name='imageFile'` is not `focusable.`.

Is there anyway to fix this without JavaScript ?

```html
<div>
  <label for="imageFile" class="button">Image</label>
  <input type="file" required id="imageFile" name="imageFile" style="display:none" />
</div>
```

Comment: make it in absolute position and off the screen, :possible style  `position:absolute;right:100vw`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304472/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable

Comment: How do you expect a user to fill out this input field if they can't even see it?

Comment: @cars10m clicking on the label should focus the input and let you choose a file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An invalid form control with name...is not focusable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304472/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable)

Comment: @D.Pardal probably, but the request is without javascript ;)

Comment: I just tried it out (without "required" attribute): yes you *can* put the focus on the invisible input dialogue, but you cannot see, if and when any files were actually picked.

Comment: @cars10m its html5 ,  click on link label generate click on input .  G-Cyrillus idea with out of screen good , but required warning out of screen to :(

Comment: opacity could also be an idea aside absolute ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus hm intresting 'hack' make opacity 0 and position absolute under label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 'hack' solution , thx  @G-Cyrillus.

```
[type='file'] {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Required alert work fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove required because the display is none. The user can't modify the value of the input if it not displayed, so why it will be required.