# can't update products in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, updates, product, downgrade

When I updated the website of my boss we ran into some problems. Woocommerce 3.0.X doesn't automatically send confirmation emails after costumers place their orders. 
Because I couldn't find a fix I downgraded the website back to 2.6.14.

This fixed the problem with our automatic emails, but now we aren't able to save any changes to excisting products. We can make the changes but the button doesn't do anything.

When I click on the preview button, the preview opens and the product starts showing the spinner icon as if it is saving. The icons keeps spinning for forever though, and the product does not save.

My error log doesn't show any errors. I suspect it has something to do with autosaving but I'm not sure. Any help would be very much appreciated.

EDIT* 
I have tried updating products without any other plugins enabled and it still doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are there any js errors in console?

Comment: I'll check, you mean while editing the products right?

Comment: Yes, thank you! 

There are 2 errors: 

An invalid form control with name='_download_limit' is not focusable.

An invalid form control with name='_download_expiry' is not focusable.

I have no idea what they mean though.

Comment: Actually, issue seems some what different but, for now you can try adding "novalidate" to the form as it says here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148080/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable

or you should try deactivate all plugin except woocommerce. If that fixes the problem then activate the plugins one by one.

Comment: Again, thanks for the great support! I have tried with all plugins disabled but the problem remains. I was just reading the same question you linked to, but I have no idea what form I should add the novalidate to.

Comment: Adding "novalidate" to form is not recommended though. Because it will be a change in core file. Btw can't you upgrade to 3.0.X and configure emails? - it would take less time than debugging/fixing this

Comment: Because configuring emails is I don't think a big task. Is there any problem doing that?

Comment: Yes I could try that. How would you suggest configuring the emails? My guess would be through SMTP since many people are having the same email issues. [link] (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/3-0-issues-cannot-add-order-email-not-sent-for-new-order-or-other-status/). If you post your comment as an anwser I can give you the earned credit!

Comment: Thanks.!! I've posted answer. You can accept and upvote it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:** When **Downgrade woocomerce** from **3.0** to **2.6** now we aren't **able to save any** changes to excisting products. We can make the changes but the button doesn't do anything.

**Solution:** Its simple. 
1. Just edit your Product.
2. Tick on **DOWNLOADABLE** (where we give price for products)
3. make **value** 0 where its -1 in **Download limit** and **download expiry** box.
4. uncheck again downloadable (if product is not downlaodable)
 Click **Update** button.

Comment: I'm sorry for not posting this awnser myself. I just saw my negative reputation and understand your frustration. Thank you for summarising.

Comment: I just made every thing simple for any newbie who got same error. bcz i got this and it wasted my time. and i dont want same for others :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Ideally it should work without SMTP plugin if its your staging/live server. But an SMTP plugin should work if its not working normally.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try your solution. I can't upvote yet since my reputation is too low.

Comment: Thank you! Very glad you repied to my question.

Comment: You're Welcome! :)