# An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable with type=number and decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I know this topic has been quite active in SO, but now I seem to have found something strange with `input` fields with `type="number"` and decimal numbers. My code is something like this:

```js
function Sum(){
  var f = document.myform;
  var num1 = f.num1.value;
  if (isNumber(num1)){
    alert(parseFloat(num1));
  }
}

function isNumber(n) {
    return (!isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n) && n >= 0);
}
```

```css
#num1 {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="javascript:void(0);">
  <input id="num1" type="number" value="1.5">
  <input id="run_button" class="button" type="submit" onclick="Sum()"/>
</form>
```

Every time I put decimal numbers in number fields, I get this error, but if the numbers are without the dot, the error does not appear. You can test in [test form](http://autocosts.work/XX).

[image]

Comment: Works in Chrome for me -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/143226rj/1/

Comment: Isn't this related to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148080/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable), i.e. elements hidden with `display:none` having issues with validation etc ?

Comment: @adeneo I don't want to bother you, but try this [test form](http://autocosts.work/XX). It works fine with normal numbers, but with decimal numbers (with dot), it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This solved my problem

```
<input type='number' min='0' step='Any'/>
```