# How to get not focusable input form control by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label class="btn btn-theme">
        <input type="file" name="file" value="" style="display:none;" required=""> click Me to choose file
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-success">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="yes" style="display:none;" required=""> Are You agree ?
    </label>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
</form>
```

i want to show alert whenever user haven't selected any file or not agree and press Submit button in my given code.
 right now it giving `"An invalid form control with name='file' is not focusable."`
I know the reason behind it but how can i alert my user that you have not selected anything.
I do not like to use Jquery Submit or show them choose file icon.

**Is there any way to get that element (with help of jQuery) on which browser trying to focus ?**

Comment: Could your submit button just call a function that tests whether the input contains any data.  You might also consider that since your input is required the submit button might not be available.

Comment: @Dean , yes i can but in my actual code there are more than 20 required inputs. so its to lengthy to validate all of them. I just want to know that is there anything in jQuery which gives me that, the browser is trying to focusing which element of DOM.

Answer (score 0):

This other issue seems to be similar.  Can you add novalidate attribute to your form? This is seen here: [An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148080/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable)

Comment: No, If I had to do this then simply i remove required attribute from all inputs. but i want to show alert or error if users does'n select file or check radio's. I have seen this answer, but it is not solving my problem

Comment: You might have a look at this page: it offers some very elegent solutions to what you are trying to do: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has a focus method that should do what you want.

Create a variable somewhere that will keep track of whether the user has clicked on an input.

```
var inputFocusOccured = false;
```

Then use the focus method to change the variable whenever a user clicks or touches an input.

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    inputFocusOccured = true;
});
```

Then when the user clicks submit have it check if the value is true or false

```
$("#SubmitBtn").click(function() {
    if(inputFocusOccured === false){
        alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    }
});
```