# TinyMCE - An invalid form control with name='content' is not focusable

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I use TinyMCE 4 and this is my code for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
       tinymce.init({
         selector: 'textarea[name=content]',
         plugins: 'image code',
         toolbar: 'undo redo | link image | code',
         image_title: true, 
         automatic_uploads: true,
         file_picker_types: 'image', 
         file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
           var input = document.createElement('input');
           input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
           input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
           input.onchange = function() {
             var file = this.files[0];
             var reader = new FileReader();
             reader.onload = function () {
             var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
             var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
             var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
             var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
             blobCache.add(blobInfo);
             cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
           };
           reader.readAsDataURL(file);
         };
         input.click();
       }
     });  
</script>
```

and I have one problem. When I click on the "submit" button, the form isn' t send but in web browser console I have error: "An invalid form control with name='content' is not focusable."

Please can you help me, how can I solve this problem simply? For all advice thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your html,  please

Comment: Please, can you describe what do you mean?

Comment: Where  are you set your texarea with [name=content]?

Comment: <textarea name="content" required="required"><?= $review['content'] ?></textarea>   in the same file, as is tinymce editor.

Answer (score 17):

The issue comes from tinymce hiding the textarea. Remove the required attribute and it should be fixed!

Comment: Can you add more details, why removing **required** will solve the problem?

Comment: Of course, check the best answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148080/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable

Comment: Removing "required" attribute is not a solution. We add "required" when this field is required and not because of whim.

The solution for TinyMCE is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60834085/how-to-make-textarea-filed-mandatory-when-ive-applied-tinymce/66032994#66032994

Comment: Thanks mate this was really helpful for me my code works well.

Answer (score 0):

I've been around this issue for a couple of hours and posting via Ajax the TinyMCE data from the textarea field always arrived `null` at the controller.

**Solved** by changing just one bit of the ajax request from `dataType: "json",` to **`dataType: "jsonp",`**. Note that by adding the **p** in dataType was the solution.

Hope it helps anybody experiencing the same issue.