# An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable error Material ui input type file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I have a form built as functional component using `Material ui` which contains markups like below

```
<form className={classes.container} onSubmit={show}>
<Grid container item xs={12} alignItems="center">
  <input
   accept=".xlsx,.xls"
   className={classes.input}
   id="text-button-file"
   required
   multiple
   type="file"
   onChange={getfileToUpload}
/>
  <Button type= "submit" className={classes.reTest}>
    Show
  </Button>
</Grid>
</Form>
```

Now, in my container component, i want to validate if file is really uploaded or not, if not then want to display a validation error message that "Please upload file", but at present if file is not available its giving error as "An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable" in console. Below is my validation function.

```
valid = () => {
    debugger;
    if (!this.state.fileName) {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

What's wrong here? How to use file upload inbuilt validation?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add name attribute your input field

```
     <input
   accept=".xlsx,.xls"
   className={classes.input}
   id="text-button-file"
   name='file-input'
   required
   multiple
   type="file"
   onChange={getfileToUpload}
/>
```

You can also refer to this link : [An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148080/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable)