# Submit button doesn't work after adding jQuery script

Tags: html, jquery, django-forms, django-templates, form-submit

I use class-based views in a Django app. UpdateView works fine with the same template, form and model like CreateView. But CreateView has the problem with submitting a form. I press the submit button and nothing happens. When I remove `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>` from `<head>` tag it submits.
But I need this script for rendering SimpleMDEField.

`Note` creates and saves good in the admin panel.
Also works this on js console:

```js
let form = document.getElementById('add');
form.submit()
```

#### models.py

```py
class Note(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=254, editable=False, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, editable=False
    )
    source = models.URLField(blank=True, default='')
    body_raw = SimpleMDEField()
    body_html = models.TextField(max_length=40000, default='', blank=True)
```

#### views.py

```py
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class NoteCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Note
    fields = ['title', 'source', 'body_raw']
    template_name = 'notes/create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

#### urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', NoteList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('view/<str:slug>/', NoteDetailView.as_view(), name='note'),
    path('add/', NoteCreateView.as_view(), name='add'),
    path('update/<str:slug>/', NoteUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('delete/<str:slug>/', NoteDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
]
```

#### create.html

```html
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Create Note{% endblock %}

{% block extrahead %}
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    {{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

    <form method="post" id="add">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Save Note">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

#### base.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load static %}

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}project name{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block extrahead %}{% endblock %}
</head>

</body>
    <div style="max-width: 1490px; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px;">
        {% block main %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed an error `An invalid form control with name='body_raw' is not focusable` in js console. I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148080/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable) after googling the problem. And one answer helped.

I added `novalidate` to the form.

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
```

Everything works fine.