# Python & Django web app button click not working

Tags: python, django, button

**updated
I had a web app developed by another person who is no longer willing to help with bugs. I have some experience, but not enough apparently to fix this issue.

In the web app, there is a button that does nothing when clicked. It should save user information to a database. I do not understand how the click event ties back to possibly the `views.py` file.

In my `templates/add-inventory.html` I see:

```
<a href="{% url 'crm:inventory' %}" class="btn btn-light rounded-pill me-1"> Cancel </a>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success rounded-pill"> Save </button>
```

The save button is not doing anything.
I see in the `views.py`:

```
@login_required(login_url='crm:login')
@permission_required("crm.add_inventory", raise_exception=True)
def addInventory(request):
    form = InventoryForm()
    staff = User.objects.all().order_by('first_name')
    vendor_form = VendorForm()

    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InventoryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            inventory_instance = form.save()
            
            if not request.POST.get('vendor'):
                vendor_form = VendorForm(request.POST)
                
                if vendor_form.is_valid():
                    vendor = vendor_form.save(commit=False)
                    vendor.added_by = request.user
                    vendor.save()
                    inventory_instance.vendor = vendor
                    inventory_instance.save()
                
            stocks = request.POST.getlist('stock')
            for i in range(len(staff)):
                if int(stocks[i]) > 0:
                    InventoryStock.objects.create(
                        inventory = inventory_instance,
                        user = staff[i],
                        stock = stocks[i]
                    )
                    
            messages.success(request, 'Item added successfully')
            return redirect('crm:inventory')
```

How does the button call the code in `views.py`? Any help is appreciated.
I downloaded all files locally and am using VS Code to debug, but have made no progress.

I added `name=addInventory"` to the add-`inventory.html` file as shown below
This did nothing.

```
<a href="{% url 'crm:inventory' %}" class="btn btn-light rounded-pill me-1"> Cancel </a>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success rounded-pill" name="AddInventory"> Save </button>
```

The code below is from the `urls.py`  file as requested. Hope this is the info you needed.

```
 path('inventory', inventory, name='inventory'),
 path('inventory/add', addInventory, name='add-inventory'),   
 path('inventory/update/<int:pk>', updateInventory, name='update-inventory'),
 path('inventory/delete/<int:pk>', deleteInventory, name='delete-inventory')
```

I tried to locate the POST section in the code. I think this is it (found in add-inventory.html):

```
<div class="card bg-info-subtle shadow-none position-relative overflow-hidden mb-4">
    <div class="card-body px-4 py-3">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-9">
                <h4 class="fw-semibold mb-8">Add Inventory</h4>
                <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                            <a class="text-muted text-decoration-none" href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                            <a class="text-muted text-decoration-none" href="{% url 'crm:inventory' %}">Inventory</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page">Add Inventory</li>
                    </ol>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="widget-content searchable-container list">
    <div class="p-3">

        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="py-3">
                        <h4>Item Info</h4>
                        <p>The information about the item number, machine it belongs to, decription of the item and the prices.>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card card-body">
                        {{form.name | as_crispy_field}}
                        {{form.item_number | as_crispy_field}}
                        {{form.machine | as_crispy_field}}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                {% crispy_addon form.buying_price prepend="$" %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                {% crispy_addon form.selling_price prepend="$" %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {{form.taxable | as_crispy_field}}
                        {{form.description | as_crispy_field}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="py-3">
                        <h4>Vendor Info</h4>
                        <p>You can select the vendor of the inventory item or you can add new vendor and it will be assocciated with the item.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card card-body">
                        <div class="row mb-2">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <div id="vendor-field">
                                    {{form.vendor | as_crispy_field}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="d-grid">
                                    <a type="button" id="toggle-button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 30px"><i class="fa fa-plus me-2"></i> Add</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        
                        <div id="add-vendor-content" style="display:none">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    {{vendor_form.status|as_crispy_field}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    {{vendor_form.name|as_crispy_field}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    {{vendor_form.phone_number|as_crispy_field}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    {{vendor_form.email|as_crispy_field}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    {{vendor_form.address|as_crispy_field}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-header mb-2">
                                <h5 class="text-center">Contact Person</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    {{vendor_form.contact_person_name|as_crispy_field}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    {{vendor_form.contact_person_phone_number|as_crispy_field}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    {{vendor_form.contact_person_email|as_crispy_field}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="py-3">
                        <h4>Stock Availability</h4>
                        <p>It will show how much stock every staff user have right now</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card card-body">
                        
                        {% for i in staff %}
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <input type="text" name="staff_user" id="id_staff_user" class="form-control" value="{{i.get_full_name}}" readonly/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <input type="number" name="stock" id="id_stock" class="form-control" value="0"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                            
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="py-3">
                        <h4>Notes</h4>
                        <p>You can store the related notes to the instance here</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card card-body">
                        {{form.notes|as_crispy_field}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card card-body">
                        <div class="text-end">
                            <a href="{% url 'crm:add-inventory' %}" class="btn btn-light rounded-pill me-1">Cancel</a>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success rounded-pill">Save</button>
```

I changed the line below to add `action="{% url 'crm:add-inventory' %}"`, but this did not help.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'crm:add-inventory' %}">
```

urls.py file from config folder:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    path('', include(('crm.urls', 'crm'), namespace='crm')),
]

urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

urls.py file from crm folder:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *
from .models import *
app_name = "crm" #I added this, it was not originally here

urlpatterns = [
    path('', login, name='login'),
    path('logout', logout, name='logout'),
    
    path('dashboard', dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('dashboard/stats', dashboardStatistics, name='dashboard-statistics'),
    path('dashboard/monthly-sale', monthlySaleChart, name='dashboard-monthly-sale'),
    path('dashboard/revenue-update', revenueUpdateChart, name='dashboard-revenue-update'),
    path('dashboard/tax-update', taxUpdateChart, name='dashboard-tax-update'),
    path('dashboard/recent-sales-order', receentSalesOrders, name='dashboard-recent-sales-orders'),
    path('dashboard/recent-invoices', receentInvoices, name='dashboard-recent-invoices'),
    path('dashboard/recent-payments', receentPayments, name='dashboard-recent-payments'),
    path('dashboard/recent-quotations', receentQuotations, name='dashboard-recent-quotations'),
    
    
    path('profile', profile, name='profile'),
    
    
    path('staff', users, name='staff-users'),
    path('staff/add', addUser, name='add-staff-user'),
    path('staff/update/<int:id>', updateUser, name='update-staff-user'),
    path('staff/delete/<int:id>', deleteUser, name='delete-staff-user'),
    
    
    path('roles', roles, name='roles'),
    path('role/add', addRole, name='add-role'),
    path('role/update/<int:id>', updateRole, name='update-role'),
    path('role/delete/<int:id>', deleteRole, name='delete-role'),
    
    
    path('companies', companies, name='companies'),
    path('company/add', addCompany, name='add-company'),
    path('company/update/<int:pk>', updateCompany, name='update-company'),
    path('company/delete/<int:pk>', deleteCompany, name='delete-company'),
    
    
    path('contacts', contacts, name='contacts'),
    path('contact/add', addContact, name='add-contact'),
    path('contact/update/<int:pk>', updateContact, name='update-contact'),
    path('contact/delete/<int:pk>', deleteContact, name='delete-contact'),
    
    
    path('machines', machines, name='machines'),
    path('machine/add', addMachine, name='add-machine'),
    path('machine/update/<int:pk>', updateMachine, name='update-machine'),
    path('machine/delete/<int:pk>', deleteMachine, name='delete-machine'),
    
    path('inventory', inventory, name='inventory'),
    path('inventory/add', addInventory, name='add-inventory'),
    path('inventory/update/<int:pk>', updateInventory, name='update-inventory'),
    path('inventory/delete/<int:pk>', deleteInventory, name='delete-inventory'),

    path('settings/invoice', invoiceSetting, name='invoice-setting'),
    
    path('invoices', invoices, name='invoices'),
    path('invoice/add', addInvoice, name='add-invoice'),
    path('invoice/export/<str:inv_no>', exportInvoice, name='export-invoice'),
    path('invoice/delete/<int:pk>', deleteInvoice, name='delete-invoice'),
    
    
    path('credit-notes', creditnotes, name='credit-notes'),
    path('delivery-order', deliveryOrders, name='delivery-orders'),
    
    path('credit-note/export/<str:cn_number>', exportCreditNote, name='export-credit-note'),
    path('credit-note/delete/<int:pk>', deleteCreditNote, name='delete-credit-note'),
    
    
    path('settings/estimate', estimateSetting, name='estimate-setting'),
    
    
    path('estimates', estimates, name='estimates'),
    path('estimate/add', addEstimate, name='add-estimate'),
    path('estimate/view/<str:est_no>', viewEstimate, name='view-estimate'),
    path('estimate/update/<str:est_no>', updateEstimate, name='update-estimate'),
    path('estimate/copy/<str:est_no>', copyEstimate, name='copy-estimate'),
    path('estimate/convert/<str:est_no>', convertEstimate, name='convert-estimate'),
    path('estimate/export/<str:est_no>', exportEstimate, name='export-estimate'),
    path('estimate/delete/<int:pk>', deleteEstimate, name='delete-estimate'),
    
    path('quotation/item/delete/<int:pk>', deleteEstimateItem, name='delete-estimate-item'),
    
    # Payment Routes
    path('settings/stripe-keys', stripeApiKeySetting, name='stripe-keys-setting'),
    path('payment/make-payment/<str:uuid>', makePayment, name='make-payment'),
    path('payment/charge', CreateCheckoutSession, name='charge'),
    path('payment/success/<str:uuid>', successMsg, name='success'),
    path('payment/error', errorMsg, name='cancel'),
    path('payment/paid', alreadyPaid, name='already-paid'),
    
    path('service-reports', saleOrders, name='sale-orders'),
    path('service-report/add', addSaleOrder, name='add-sale-order'),
    path('service-report/view/<str:so_number>', viewSaleOrder, name='view-sale-order'),
    path('service-report/update/<str:so_number>', updateSaleOrder, name='update-sale-order'),
    path('service-report/copy/<str:so_number>', copySaleOrder, name='copy-sale-order'),
    path('service-report/export/<str:so_number>', exportSaleOrder, name='export-sale-order'),
    path('service-report/delete/<int:pk>', deleteSaleOrder, name='delete-sale-order'),
    
    path('sale-order/item/delete/<int:pk>', deleteSaleOrderItem, name='delete-sale-order-item'),
    
    path('delivery-order/create/<str:invoice_number>', createDeliveryOrder, name='create-delivery-order'),
    path('delivery-order/export/<str:do_number>', exportDeliveryOrder, name='export-delivery-order'),
    
    path('payments', payments, name='payments'),
    path('payments/update/<int:pk>', updatePayment, name='update-payment'),
    path('payments/delete/<int:pk>', deletePayment, name='delete-payment'),
    

    path('vendors', vendors, name='vendors'),
    path('vendor/update/<int:id>', updateVendor, name='update-vendor'),
    path('vendor/delete/<int:id>', deleteVendor, name='delete-vendor'),
    
    
    path('reporting/soa', soa, name='soa'),
    path('reporting/soa/export', exportsoa, name='export-soa'),
    
    path('reporting/tax-report', taxReport, name='tax-report'),
    path('reporting/tax-report/export', exportTaxReport, name='export-tax-report'),
    
    path('reporting/machines-report', machinesReport, name='machines-report'),
    
    path('reporting/debit-report', debitReport, name='debit-report'),
    path('reporting/debit-report/export', exportDebitReport, name='export-debit-report'),
    
    
    path('ajax/machines', clientMachinesFilterAjax, name='client-machines-filter-ajax'),
]
```

The original developer sent me some changes. Wimerge showed that he had to add a new view and changed the update inventory file as shown in the pic below
[Winmerge view[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS0Uh.png)

Comment: Could you attach a file - urls.py , it describes url templates

Comment: Edited post. Let me know if this helps or if more info is required.

Comment: {I added name=addInventory" to the add-inventory.html file as shown below This did nothing.} which won't solve this, because that's not a fix for this.

Answer (score 1):

**More general explanation**

Here is how django works.

1. First user click on `button / link`
2. This `button or link` post or request information from specific `url`
3. This url must match one from django `urls.py`
4. This `url` must be connected to a `view` inside `views.py`, this view is the place where actual operations happen

---

**Problem could be**

- breakpoint in above linkage.

Or

- error in django view/code

---

**Answer :-**

As of given info, we only see 1,3,4 steps.

- We can't see `post form` `action value` in the give info on question.

Or

- we can't see `javascript/jquery` code for custom form `post/upload`.

**One of them is a must.**

So,

cheack post form action valve, and check it matches one from django `urls.py`.
It could be something as below(any of below).

- {% url 'add-inventory' %}
- {% url 'crm:addInventory' %}
- inventory/add

Or

Cheack in custom form submit js/jquery code for valid url.

Comment: I added what I believe is the post section to the original post. Is this the correct part of code?

Comment: What did the `{% url 'crm:add-inventory' %} ` generate? This is a solution if there's no custom post/ajax os used.

Comment: Yes. You located correct post section. Does server receive any request, any view get called?

Comment: adding "{% url 'crm:add-inventory' %}" did not help.

Comment: Still nothing happens when clicking the save button. If custom code is used, where might it be? hopefully there is a standard location.

Comment: I get it. Does server receive any request, any view get called? What did the {% url 'crm:add-inventory' %}  generate?

Comment: I updated my answer. Look at last part.

Comment: Did you problem got solved by my answer?

Comment: Ive added many break points but do not see any view get called when clicking save.

Comment: What did the {% url 'crm:add-inventory' %} generate?

Comment: adding  `{% url 'crm:add-inventory' %} ` did not make any views get called. I can breakpoint other buttons in the code for similar functions and it works ok. Not sure what I am missing??

Comment: Try using one of below, `{% url 'add-inventory' %}` Or 
`{% url 'crm:addInventory' %}` .

Comment: I did try both but found no joy

Comment: Does click on the button trigger any request, on browser console? Open browser console and the click the save button. Check if browser console show any messages. Or check browser network tab.

Comment: I will try again and use the browser console. Thanks for this.

Comment: When I click save I am getting the following from the console (cntrl+shift+j) An invalid form control with name='name' is not focusable

Comment: See, https://stackoverflow.com/q/22148080/13861187 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/28340579/13861187 .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already provided `app_name = "crm"` in your `urls.py` you have just to change the url of your button to `{% url 'crm:add-inventory' %}` the name you provided in your `urls.py` file.

if you have already setup VSCode to debug properly you should be able to put  breakpoints in your `inventory` view and in `addInventory` view, you'd notice that you're calling the first one since its name is inventory

Comment: I put breakpoints in both, but none get called by this button. The add inventory seems to be called when opening the screen to add an individual inventory item (when the form opens), but nothing when pressing save. I changed the text as you stated but found no joy

Comment: did you made sure that you have app_name = "crm" in your urls.py file?

Comment: There are 2 urls.py files. One in crm folder and one in config folder. I did not see this in either. Which one should it be in? Does it have to be in any certain spot within the file?

Comment: add it in urls.py of your crm app, add it before the urlpatterns definition

Comment: I added it as requested, but had no change.

Comment: that's weird, can you provide the base urls.py of your project, and it would also be helpful if you provide the server logs when clicking the button just to make sure which url is called

Comment: I didnt know there were log files - i will look into where they are. If I have to enable this function - please let me know

Comment: let's just have an idea about your base urls.py file and how are you running your application, typically the logs will be available in your terminal with you run ./manage.py runserver

Comment: I added both urls.py files to the original post. I will look at the terminal window to see if there is more information.

Comment: i will try to reproduce your situation and comeback to you

Comment: Thank you! I am re-downloading all of the files from the server so I can debug with a fresh set and will check the terminal window (Cntrl+Shift+J) this will show if something is being called by the save button?

Comment: @Tom Please don't tell you weren't restarting the server when you were making those changes

Comment: Lol. I am not making the changes to the server. I have everything local on my pc and running from there. If I change the button shape, I can see the change when debugging

Comment: When I click save I am getting the following from the console (cntrl+shift+j) An invalid form control with name='name' is not focusable.

Comment: I tried your configuration and it works perfectly on my machine, i'm afraid I can't help further unless you're willing to have a deeper discussion with a screen sharing on discord here's my username jyssy

Comment: i would love your help.